# dbt - stage_external_sources - partitioning

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I'm trying to do a nice partitioning of the incremental files delivered on azure blob storage.

However, I can't get partition column and table columns to play nice.
If I remove partition column, I get all table columns specified.
If I have partition column, I only get variant column and partition column.

```
  - name: arsm
    external:
      location: '@my_azure_stage'
      file_format: 'myformat'
      pattern: '.*path.*tablename_.*'
      auto_refresh: false # depends on your Azure setup
      partitions:       # optional
        - name: LOAD_DATE
          data_type: date
          expression: TO_DATE(substring(metadata$filename,16,10))
      columns:
      - name: "AoNr" 
        data_type: bigint
      - name: "AoNrAlfa" 
        data_type: varchar(65)
      - name: "AoPos" 
        data_type: int
      - name: "ArtikelVariant" 
        data_type: varchar(30)
      - name: "ArtKalkBer" 
        data_type: NUMERIC
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `myformat` correctly parses the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to out-dent the `columns` array by two spaces. The `columns` array should be a top-level key of the source table, at the same level as `name` and `external`; right now you have it nested within the `external` dict.